# How to Store Shift Information in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, bson

I am migrating from SQL Server to Mongo DB.

In SQLServer, there is a Time datatype to store the Time information only. I use this to store the shift information of an employee.

For example, a regular shift starts at 9:00 AM and ends at 5:00 PM. In SQLServer, I store it as SHIFT_START_TIME(time(7), null) and SHIFT_END_TIME(time(7), null) columns.

Is there a similar way to just store Time information in Mongo ? If not what is the best way ?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB allows storing of date which include date + time. So either you store time along with date part and ignore date in your code....

But I would suggest following two alternate which I think will be better:
1. Convert time in seconds for example 9:00 AM = 9 * 60 * 60 and for 5:00 PM = (5 + 12) * 60 * 60
2. Store Time as string

In either of the approach you choose you will require to make some changes to your code to handle accordingly...